# Converting GB into TB in the script

Tags: awk, scripting

It should be like this `0.972` `/` `3` = `0.324` is the actual value here. So if the value of `HDD Used` is in **G** so it should be calculated it in TB and then do the division.

```
# isi storagepool list -v |
awk '
    /Requested Protection:/ { parity=substr($NF,length($NF)-1,1) }
    /Nodes:/ { nodes=$NF }
    /HDD Total/ { hdd_total=$NF }
    /HDD Used/ { hdd_used=$NF }
    END {
        multiplier=nodes-parity
        total=hdd_total/nodes*multiplier
        used=hdd_used/nodes
        print "parity =" parity
        print "NodeNumber =" nodes
        print "Total =" total "TB"
        print "Effective Total volume = " total*0.8 " TB"
        print "USED =" used "%"
        print "Effective used=" used*multiplier*0.8 " TB"
        print "Available volume=" (hdd_total-hdd_used)/nodes*multiplier*0.8 " TB" }'
parity =1
NodeNumber =3
Total =37.3013TB
Effective Total volume = 29.8411 TB
USED =324.307%
Effective used=518.891 TB
Available volume=-489.05 TB
```

**Actual output of `HDD Used` in the command `isi storagepool list --v` is G as mention below and we need the calculation in TB**

```
# isi storagepool list -v
                Name: s210_21tb_800gb-ssd_128gb
               Nodes: 1, 2, 3
Requested Protection: +2d:1n
                Type: nodepool
            Children: -
               Usage
                HDD Used: 972.905G
               HDD Total: 55.9520T
              HDD % Used: 1.70%
                SSD Used: 0b
               SSD Total: 0b
              SSD % Used: 0.00%

# cat isi.py
isi storagepool list -v |
awk '
    /Requested Protection:/ { parity=substr($NF,length($NF)-1,1) }
    /Nodes:/ { nodes=$NF }
    /HDD Total/ { hdd_total=$NF }
    /HDD Used/ { hdd_used=num2gb($NF) }
    END {
        multiplier=nodes-parity
        total=hdd_total/nodes*multiplier
        used=hdd_used/nodes
        print "parity =" parity
        print "NodeNumber =" nodes
        print "Total = " total " TB"
        print "Effective Total volume = " total*0.8 " TB"
        print "USED =" used "%"
        print "Effective used=" used*multiplier*0.8 " TB"
        print "Available volume=" (hdd_total-hdd_used)/nodes*multiplier*0.8 " TB" }'
```

**Edit 1 @ilkkachu Answer**

```
# cat isi.py
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
isi storagepool list -v | awk 'function num2gb(n) { if (n ~ /T$/) return n * 1; return n*1024; }
    /Requested Protection:/ { parity=substr($NF,length($NF)-1,1) }
    /Nodes:/ { nodes=$NF }
    /HDD Total/ { hdd_total=$NF }
    /HDD Used/ { hdd_used=num2gb($NF) }
    END {
        multiplier=nodes-parity
        total=hdd_total/nodes*multiplier
        used=hdd_used/nodes
        print "parity =" parity
        print "NodeNumber =" nodes
        print "Total = " total " TB"
        print "Effective Total volume = " total*0.8 " TB"
        print "USED =" used "%"
        print "Effective used=" used*multiplier*0.8 " TB"
        print "Available volume=" (hdd_total-hdd_used)/nodes*multiplier*0.8 " TB" }'
```

**Output**

```
cat storageinfo_example_info
parity =1
NodeNumber =3
Total = 37.3013 TB
Effective Total volume = 29.8411 TB
USED =333925%
Effective used=534281 TB
Available volume=-534251 TB
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the input is sometimes in GB, sometimes in TB, I'd write a function to handle both cases ([functions in GNU awk's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Definition-Syntax.html#Definition-Syntax)):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
function num2gb(n) { 
    if (n ~ /T$/) return n * 1024;    # if TB, scale
    return n * 1;                     # else assume GB. * 1 converts to number
}  
{ printf "%.2f G\n", num2gb($1) }     # print, as an example
```

Then you could use the function when reading the numbers from the input to get the numbers in GB:

```
/HDD Total/ { hdd_total = num2gb($NF) }
/HDD Used/ { hdd_used = num2gb($NF) }
```

Add cases for `MB` and `PB` if required, and check if the program producing your input thinks in powers of `1024` or powers of `1000`.

When outputting, you can of course choose the multiplier as you like.

The above would be a self-contained `awk` script, on the command line you'd do something like

```
$ somecmd | awk 'function num2gb(n) { if (n ~ /T$/) return n * 1024; return n*1; }  
   /some pattern/ { some action }
   /other pattern/ { something with num2gb($n) ... } '
```

Comment: Do I need to create a new script for it and call the file or just need to add it in the current script. the original script is edited in the question.

Comment: @Shanker, just add the function part to the start of the script. I put the printing rule there just as an example.

Comment: Not getting the output, I have edited the question.

Comment: @Shanker, ahhh, you need the function in the _awk_ script, so on the same command line as the rest of it (edited an example). For longer scripts, it may be useful to save the awk script into a file, and then run the script with `awk -f myscript.awk` instead of putting the whole script on the command line. Or with just `./myscript.awk` if the hashbang line is there, and the script is executable. Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: I want the output in TB and the `isi storagepool list -v` gives it in `GB`. I have reversed the function as shown in the question. Its helped me but the only thing which missing is the decimal numbers are getting merged with the actual count. remaining is fine.